# Additional funding for PhD students

Tags: phd, funding, europe

Are there 'additional' grants/fellowships available for Mathematics PhD students (who already have their funded positions) in Europe? In other words, does any program analogous to the ERC Starting Grants exist for PhD students?

Comment: What were you hoping to get funded as a PhD candidate , if your position is already funded?

Comment: There are many small travel grants that I know of (in physics at least, there must be similar in maths), but nothing as big as an ERC. Fellowships for PhDs do exist, but as mmeent alluded to, you're unlikely to be awarded more than one at a time (in fact, it's probably against the rules of any funding body to do so).

Answer (score 2):

As for a EU-wide database of research funding opportunities, see EURAXESS:

1. Go to [EURAXESS Funding Search](https://euraxess.ec.europa.eu/funding/search).
2. Select your `RESEARCH FIELD` (probably "Formal Sciences").
3. Select your `FUNDING TYPE` ("Funding"? "Mobility Incoming/Outgoing"? "Travel Grants"?).
4. Select your `CAREER STAGE` (probably "First Stage Researcher" up to the point of PhD).
5. Click on `Search` and browse through the results!

Other than that, there are also *national* databases. If you tell us the country of your affiliation, perhaps we could link to it. (E.g. https://grants.at/ for Austria.)